# Should I keep Vinayak Chaturthi or Sankasti Chaturthi Vrat every month?

Tags: festivals, fasting, vrata

People advised me to keep Sankasti Chaturthi  ...Later I found out about Vinayaka Chaturthi too ... So, Can I take only Sankasti Chaturthi every month or do I have to take both every month ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE. Kindly visit [How Does a New User Get Started on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). This question looks like an opinion based question and is bound to be closed. Have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: Its better to ask the Purohit who advised you. But both fasts are for Lord Ganesha.

Comment: AFAIK Its not necessary to keep both these vratas together. Most of the people in Maharashtra from where I am  only keep the Sankasti Chaturthi  fasting vrata. But its entirely upto an individual , if it is poosible he can follow both or only one of them. keeping both of them is offcourse more beneficial.